# Adding NSNotification observer inside a UITableViewCell is retrieved by another Cell after scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom UITableViewCell class named tableCell (original yes!), in it I implement the `awakeFromNib`, `prepareForReuse` and my own methods:

This, is `askForThumbnail`:

```
- (void)askForThumbnail {

    if (!self.thumbnailAsked)
    {
        // ask for thumbnail here
        NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"th:%@", self.remotePath];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(listenToThumbnail:) name:name object:nil];

        self.thumbnailTask = [self.appDelegate.taskManager launchThumbnailWithRemotePath:self.remotePath];
        self.thumbnailAsked = YES;
    }
}
```

`listenToThumbnail`:

```
- (void)listenToThumbnail: (NSNotification *)myNotif {

    self.thumbnail = [[myNotif object] thumbnail];
    self.thumbnailView.image = self.thumbnail;
    #pragma mark TODO
}
```

and `initCellWithRemotePath`:

```
- (void)initCellWithRemotePath: (NSString *)remotePath {

    if (!self.remotePath)
    {
        self.remotePath = remotePath;
        self.titleLabel = ((UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:10]);
        self.thumbnailView = ((UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:30]);
        self.infoLabel = ((UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:40]);
    }
}
```

My ViewController `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // real awoke
    tableCell *cell = (tableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellFile" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // init this cell
    [cell initCellWithRemotePath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iphone/test/IMG_%04ld.JPG", indexPath.row + 1]];

    // ask the thumbnail to the server
    [cell askForThumbnail];

    if (cell.thumbnail)
        cell.thumbnailView.image = cell.thumbnail;

    cell.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"IMG_%04ld.JPG", indexPath.row + 1];

    return cell;
}
```

**Explanation:**

When I scroll down this tableView, I have my cell's imageView that don't have the good images (`cell.imageView.image`)...

And when I want to scroll up, my top cells (1, 2, ...) have bottom cell images...
I think there is a problem with my `NSNotifications` and my `observers`, because if I delete the `if (!self.thumbnailAsked)` check in `askForThumbnail`, if a cell ask for a thumbnail and I scroll, that's another cell that catch the notification.

it can also come from the iOS notification system, that speak to something else that the `self` asked in `addObserver` function... or something like that...

Comment: Just want to verify; you are making an async call to a backend, therefore you wish to use lazy loading?

Comment: Your problem is that by the time your notification fires the cell could have been reused. You need to store the indexPath that you are retrieving the image for and when the background load is finished, check that `[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` doesn't return nil.  If it does then the cell has been scrolled out of view

Comment: @JeremyHerrero Yes I am asking for a thumbnail, my function launches a `NSUrlsession background task` and when it's done, it sends a notification that my cell catches ! (but that's not working properly...)

Comment: @Paulw11 I am catching the notification directly in the cell that launched the `background task`. But in the meantime, that cell has been reused with `prepareForReuse`. Therefore the cell with label **IMG_0015** receives the notification for the cell labelled **IMG_0002**, because I scrolled...

Comment: Yes, so you need to detect that reuse has occurred and ignore the notification.

Comment: I am OK with your solution, I will try to do that and I will get back to you.

Comment: Haha it will not work, because if I send a `notification` from the **IMG_0015** cell to itself and I scroll, the **IMG_0002** will catch the notification (I ignore it). The cell has been reused and the **IMG_0015** will not get the notification...